# How to create custom html form with redirect back with success message in silverstripe?

Tags: silverstripe-4

I am new in SilverStripe. I want to create a custom HTML form in SilverStripe.

```
<form class="form-inline" $HelloForm.FormAttributes>

<p id="{$HelloForm.FormName}_success" class="message" style="">$HelloForm.Message</p>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
</div>
$HelloForm.fields

<input type="hidden" value="{$AbsoluteLink}" name="redirectURL" class="action" id="{$HelloForm.FormName}_action_doSayHello"/>
```

And in my controller

```
public function HelloForm()
{   
    
    $form = Form::create(
        $this,
        'HelloForm'
    );
    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create('doSayHello', 'Submit')->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success')
    );
    $form = new Form($this, 'HelloForm',$actions);
    return $form;
}

public function doSayHello($data,$form)
{

    $form->sessionMessage('thanks for contact us','good');
    return $this->redirectBack();
//i am not getting success message after submit
}
```

Can I get a success message after submitting in this case?

When I use standard SilverStripe form it's working but when using custom HTML form like above I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the form via ajax, which would have many advantages.

1. The page does not have to refresh itself
2. You can animate the form after submitting, by sliding up or some kind of similar animation.
3. You can handle form states like `success` or `error`

Some example code (in jQuery):

```
let form = $('.form-inline');
    
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function() {
            $(form).slideUp();
            $('#form-state').text("Successfully submitted form.");
        }
    })
```